# Unable to lock the administration directory (sudo apt-get upgrade && apt-get update)

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am having troubles running the following command on my Linux Mint partition:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

This is the first I have ever encountered this, and I run this command every two to three days to keep my system up to date. Currently, I am getting the error message:

```
Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I am able to verify my username, (whoami returns my username), and I haven't been able to find any leads through Google or the StackExchange sites I have tried (superuser and stackoverflow). I'm perplexed.

Could this be some sort of security breach? Or (I am hoping) is my limited sysadmin knowledge the culprit? I would appreciate any input I can get, but if I have to I can wipe the partition entirely and reinstall (all of my important data is religiously redundant elsewhere, and if need be I have run scenario tests where I can restore everything in a couple of hours if need be).

Advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Root privileges are needed for `apt-get upgrade` too, so:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: My apologies, it is working. Did this just get changed in an update? I never had to type sudo twice before... Response will get answer accepted.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong, `&&` separates two commands and `sudo` applies to a single command (see [man sudo](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html)) so if it did work before, it was surely for another reason. In other words `sudo` can't know if there's something *after*, only the shell can.

Comment: My apologies, I'd been on 3 hours of sleep over a 48 hour period due to work and school, and now looking back I think I had mis-typed it prior to trying a reboot, and then just "up arrowed" for command recall after reboot, which only brought back the same misguided attempt. Thank you for your input, I feel foolish...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but it was a single installation command. Later after some searching I found that this issue can happen when another software is being installed either from the software manager or synaptic package manager. As ubuntu allows installing software only one at a time, hence the error. If the other installation is stuck or canceled, the process will still be blocked. In that case one can use the command

```
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

to kill the process. I found this [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140713080650/http://freshtutorial.com/solve-unable-lock-administration-directory-varlibdpkg/).